# Identifying district boundaries outliers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, layers

I have a Nigeria shapefile that shows the district boundaries, I also have geocordinates of some health facilities, when I visualize on QGIS, I notice outliers ; some facilities are showing in a different district boundary. E.g a facility in 'Temi' district is showing on 'Tayo' boundary. how do I identify all the outliers at once, instead of filtering district by district on QGIS. Please note the health facilities is a delimited text layer with fields by name of facilities, states, districts.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your boundary layer has an attribute that shows the district name, and assuming your facilities layer also has an attribute that shows the district it is supposed to be in, use the Join Features by Location tool to populate the facilities data with the name of the district it falls in.  Compare the two columns of the resulting data table.  Any record that does not have matching district names is either in the wrong location (or your original data was not correct).   [Here is a tutorial](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_joins.html) to get you started.